# How to update data in Vue js and Laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to update my form. For some reason, it's working in Postman but not in the browser. I'm using axios to make requests and I have v-model's on all my form fields.
I've tried with both PUT and PATCH and I getting this error respectively:

```
The PATCH method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.
```

Here is my code for loading the data in the form and the Update function:

```
editProfile(profile) {
                this.editProfileData = {...profile};
                this.showEditProfileModal();
            },

updateProfile: async function() {

                axios.patch(this.uri + '/' + this.editProfileData.id, {

                    employment_type: this.editProfileData.employment_type,
                    date_of_birth: this.editProfileData.date_of_birth,
                    experience: this.editProfileData.experience,
                    skills: this.editProfileData.skills,

                }).then(response=>{

                    this.hideEditProfileModal();
                    this.$toast.success(response.data.message);

                })

                    .catch(error=>{
                        this.$toast.error(error.response.data.message);
                    });

            },
```

Here are my routes api.php:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {

    Route::post('candidate/profile', function() {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Candidate access',
            'status_code' => 200
        ], 200);
    })->middleware('scope:candidate');

    Route::post('candidate/profile/create', function() {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Candidate access',
            'status_code' => 200
        ], 200);
    })->middleware('scope:candidate');

    // Route For Candidate Profile Pages
    Route::resource('/candidate/profile', 'CandidateProfileController', ['names'=>[

        'index'=>'candidate.profile.index',
        'create'=>'candidate.profile.create',
        'store'=>'candidate.profile.store',
        'edit'=>'candidate.profile.edit',
        'update'=>'candidate.profile.update'

    ]])->middleware('scope:candidate');


});
```

Comment: could you add your routes file(s) from laravel. According to the error there is no route for that endpoint+verb

Comment: I just added it. I'm using a resource.